# Java Matrix horizontal, vertical sum of the numbers

Tags: java, matrix

I'm writing a Java code, the task is basically to create a football League Matrix where + means victory (+3) points, = means draw (+1) point and - means lose (0) points. The code should take into consideration both horizontal and vertical lines f.e. Horizontal row means matches at home and vertical line means victories as guests. The problem is i use all the "total" points in the vertical line and so there are no points left to fill up the gaps

THE OUTPUT IM GETTING

```
Team 1  x + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + = = -  Total: 50
Team 2  + x + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + = - -  Total: 49
Team 3  + + x + + + + + + + + + + + + + + - - -  Total: 48
Team 4  + + + x + + + + + + + + + + + + = = - -  Total: 47
Team 5  + + + + x + + + + + + + + + + + = - - -  Total: 46
Team 6  + + + + + x + + + + + + + + + + - - - -  Total: 45
Team 7  + + + + + + x + + + + + + + + = = - - -  Total: 44
Team 8  + + + + + + + x + + + + + + + = - - - -  Total: 43
Team 9  + + + + + + + + x + + + + + + - - - - -  Total: 42
Team 10 + + + + + + + + + x + + + + = = - - - -  Total: 41
Team 11 + + + + + + + + + + x + + + = - - - - -  Total: 40
Team 12 + + + + + + + + + + + x + + - - - - - -  Total: 39
Team 13 + + + + + + + + + + + + x = = - - - - -  Total: 38
Team 14 + + + + + + + + + + + + = x - - - - - -  Total: 37
Team 15 + + + + + + + + + + + + - - x - - - - -  Total: 36
Team 16 + + + + + + + + + + + = = - - x - - - -  Total: 35
Team 17 + + + + + + + + + + + = - - - - x - - -  Total: 34
Team 18 + + + + + + + + + + + - - - - - - x - -  Total: 33
Team 19 + + + + + + + + + + = = - - - - - - x -  Total: 32
Team 20 + + + + + + + + + + = - - - - - - - - x  Total: 31
```

As you can see the horizontal line adds up to 50 points in the first instance and vertical means that the Team 1 lost all the other games (enemy team gets + and they get -), Everything is fine in the first half of the code since every team is winning at home and losing as guests but at the end let's take team 20. 
They WIN all the games as guests so the horizontal line adds up to 31 points but if we add all the vertical points as well they get well over the limit.
My question is how could i solve that problem

CODE ***

```
 public static void main(String []args){
        int total = 50;
        String [] [] scores = new String [20][20];
        if(total-20<0){
             System.out.println("Score cannot be negative");
             System.exit(1);
        }
        for (int i=0; i< scores.length; i++){
            int b = f;
            int f = total-i;
            for(int j=0; j< scores[i].length; j++)
            {
            if(i==j){
                scores[i][j] = "x";
            }
            if(f>=3 && i!=j){
                scores[i][j] = "+";
                f=f-3;
            }
            else if (f<=2 && f>0 && i!=j){
                scores[i][j] = "=";
                f=f-1;
            }
            else if(f==0 && i!=j)
            { 
                scores[i][j] = "-"; 
            }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Team 1  ");
        for (int i=0; i< scores.length; i++){
            int t = i+2;
            int f = total-i;
            for(int j=0; j< scores[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(scores[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            if(t==21){
            System.out.println(" Total: "+f);
            }
            else if(t<10)
            {
            System.out.println(" Total: "+f);
            System.out.print("Team "+t+"  ");    
            }
            else{
            System.out.println(" Total: "+f);
            System.out.print("Team "+t+" ");}
        }

}
```

Comment: " but if we add all the vertical points as well they get well over the limit. My question is how could i solve that problem" What is the limit and why?

Comment: The limit is the "Total" at the right side of the matrix. The task was to take a number and reduce it by 1 for each team

Comment: So the input is the totals and then you need to "balance" the score sheet for the teams' scores to fit these totals (reduced by 1 for each team)?

Comment: Yes that's what a i need to do in the end it should look something like this https://prnt.sc/sl3y9o  but instead of colors im using + - =

Comment: Determining one (of many) valid scoreboards (or if one is even possible) for a list of team totals sounds very difficult... are you sure this is what you need to do? Is this for an Algorithms class?

Comment: Yes it is for the algorithm class and it's sort of an "year ending" work which pretty much determines the mark of the semester. But yes that's the problem i have to solve.

Comment: The lecturer provided an example with a 4x4 matrix and it looked exactly like this

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do when coming up with algorithms is trying to figure out as many facts as possible that I might make use of.

### Data Facts:

```
Arbitrary Values and Rules:
  Let w = +3 points for a win
  Let l = +0 points for a loss
  Let d = +1 points for a draw
  Let each team play each other team twice
  Let w > d >= l
  Let (x,y) = point outcomes for each team in a match
  Let possibleMatchOutcomes = {(3, 0), (0, 3), (1, 1)}
  Let possibleTeamPointOutcomes = {3, 0, 1}; follows from possible match outcomes
  Let possibleLeaguePointOutcomes = {3, 2};
    the possible net points for the whole league for the possible match outcomes
    +3 for win/loss +2 for draw/draw

-------------
Input Values:
  Let targetScoresList = a list of the targeted score for each team

----------------
Computed Values:
  Let n = length(targetScoresList)
  Let leagueTargetScore = sum(targetScoresList)

  Let teamGames = 2(n - 1) = 2(20 - 1) = 38; number of games played by a team, always even
  Let leagueGames = n^2 - n = 20^2 - 20 = 380; total games played in league, always even

  Let minNet = min(possibleLeaguePointOutcomes) = 2; for outcome (d, d) 
  Let maxNet = max(possibleLeaguePointOutcomes) = 3; for outcomes (w, l) or (l, w)

  // min and max total points per team
  Let minTeamTotalPoints = teamGames * l = 38 * 0 = 0
  Let maxTeamTotalPoints = teamGames * w = 38 * 3 = 114

  // min and max total points for the whole league
  Let minLeagueTotalPoints = leagueGames * minNet = 380 * 2 = 760
  Let maxLeagueTotalPoints = leagueGames * maxNet = 380 * 3 = 1140
```

### Validity Facts:

```
when there are 20 teams, wins are worth +3, losses are worth +0, and draws are worth +1 then
   a team's score must be between 0 and 114
   total points must be an even number between 760 and 1140
```

### Algorithm:

```
check that each team's score is valid, if not then error
check that the league target score is valid, if not then error

the currentScore for each team is (teamGames * d) which is 38
the targetScore is the score that team should have according to the input
the scoreDifference is (currentScore - targetScore)

any team with a negative scoreDifference needs to gain points
any team with a positive scoreDifference needs to lose points
any team with zero scoreDifference has the right number of points,
  and could lose twice as much as win to maintain a scoreDifference of zero

start the entire grid at draw/draw for each match
a win  is a difference of +2 (since draw was +1)
a loss is a difference of -1 (since draw was +1)

the numLeagueWinLossMatches is (leagueTargetScore - minLeagueTotalPoints)
  because the net difference between a win/loss match and a draw/draw match is 1

determine the base number of wins/losses per team
  the minimum number of wins and a possible loss to make the score odd

add 1 win and 2 losses to a random team (which has at least 3 remaining draw/draw games)
each team then add +1 win +2 loss for some teams until the leagueTargetScore is reached

for each team, for its number of wins, give it wins against other teams
  so long as that other team has more losses to give, else try the next team.
```

Comment: Maybe you could give me a lead on the algorithm to pick the teams?